# Why is PyCharm telling me that one of my variables could be referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that tries to create a linear equation. For some reason, PyCharm is throwing an error in the if statement that checks `if slope == 0` saying `Local variable 'slope' might be referenced before assignment` even though I think I declared and initialized the variable no matter the case. Here is the code:

```
def solve_slopeint(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['point1'] is not None and kwargs['point2'] is not None:
        equation = [None, ' = ']  # None = placeholder for y value
        point1 = kwargs['point1']
        point2 = kwargs['point2']
        try:
            slope = (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (point2[0] - point1[0])
            slope = str(slope)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            slope_numerator = point2[1] - point1[1]
            slope_denominator = point2[0] - point1[0]
            if slope_numerator == 0:
                slope = 0  # Zero slope

            elif slope_denominator == 0:
                slope = None  # Undefined slope

        if slope == 0:
            pass

        elif slope is None:
            pass
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely isn't an error, but just a warning from the PyCharm IDE. Whenever this occurs, it is because there is a possibility that a variable is not defined later in the code. In your case, the variable that may not be defined if a certain set of conditions are True is the `slope` variable.

The `slope` variable is defined in the `try` clause and in the `except` clause in the `if` and `elif` clauses. If those are the routes the interpreter takes, then `slope` is defined. However, if the `except` clause is executed and neither the `if` nor the `elif` conditions are `True`, then `slope` will not be defined.

I understand that this scenario will never play out, as a `ZeroDivisionError` requires that the denominator of a fraction or the divisor must be zero. Since PyCharm does not necessarily see this, it gives the warning.

If you want the warning to be ignored, I recommend making the below edits:

```py
def solve_slopeint(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['point1'] is None or kwargs['point2'] is None:
        return
    equation = [None, ' = ']
    p1, p2 = kwargs['point1'], kwargs['point2']
    try:
        slope = str((p1[1]-p2[1]) / (p2[0]-p2[1]))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        slope = None

    if slope == 0:
        pass
    elif slope is Non:
        pass
```

Eliminating some of the conditions and flow control statements not only eliminates the warnings, but it also increases code readability.

Answer (score 3):

I've annotated the possible case. It may be mathematically impossible to reach, but pycharm doesn't know that. Here's what I think is happening

```
def solve_slopeint(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['point1'] is not None and kwargs['point2'] is not None:
        equation = [None, ' = ']  # None = placeholder for y value
        point1 = kwargs['point1']
        point2 = kwargs['point2']
        try:
            #### raise here, go to except
            slope = (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (point2[0] - point1[0])
            slope = str(slope)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            slope_numerator = point2[1] - point1[1]
            slope_denominator = point2[0] - point1[0]
            # != 0, go to elif
            if slope_numerator == 0:
                slope = 0  # Zero slope
            # != 0 continue past except
            elif slope_denominator == 0:
                slope = None  # Undefined slope

        # slope hasn't been defined
        if slope == 0:
            pass

        elif slope is None:
            pass
```

If in your except, after getting a false condition on `if slope_numerator == 0` and there is *truly* no other option except for your elif to be true, make your `elif` an else and your warning will go away.

EDIT: Also, as Jacob Lee pointed out, you won't get that exception on a 0 numerator, only a 0 denominator. See his answer for a more optimal path, while mine points out what pycharm is thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Python wants you to specify it on a non-logic/non-loop content inside of your function. I really don't know why but it does that and it is required, I think this will solve your problem:

```
def solve_slopeint(**kwargs):

slope = 0  # or slope = None

if kwargs['point1'] is not None and kwargs['point2'] is not None:
    equation = [None, ' = ']  # None = placeholder for y value
    point1 = kwargs['point1']
    point2 = kwargs['point2']
    try:
        slope = (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (point2[0] - point1[0])
        slope = str(slope)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        slope_numerator = point2[1] - point1[1]
        slope_denominator = point2[0] - point1[0]
        if slope_numerator == 0:
            slope = 0  # Zero slope

        elif slope_denominator == 0:
            slope = None  # Undefined slope

    if slope == 0:
        pass

    elif slope is None:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only error you are interested in capturing is the ZeroDivisionError, why not try to do it with a simple if/else statement:

```
def solve_slopeint(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['point1'] is not None and kwargs['point2'] is not None:
        point1 = kwargs['point1']
        point2 = kwargs['point2']
        slope_numerator = point2[0] - point1[0]
        slope_denominator = point2[1] - point1[1]
        if slope_denominator != 0:
            slope = slope_numerator/slope_denominator
        else:
            slope = None
    return slope
```